# How do I find out what CLR i am using?

Tags: .net, clr

Is there something available that tells me what .NET version I am using and whether it is .NET 2.0 SP1?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`Environment.Version`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.version.aspx) to find the version of the CLR you are running on.

This can be checked against the [list of framework version numbers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/kb00318785.aspx). For .NET 2.0 SP1 you'd be looking to match 2.0.50727.1433.

Comment: Thanks - Can I do this from the control panel somehow?

Comment: .NET framework versions can run side-by-side, so there will not be just one setting that tells you. Look in the `Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework` directory, and you will see a list with relevant versions that are installed on the machine.

Comment: "To determine which versions of the .NET Framework are installed, locate the %systemroot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework folder. To open this folder, you can paste this address into a Windows Explorer address bar."

Comment: Chloe - Ah, I assumed you meant which version you were using (as in running on) rather than which versions are installed. As Wim says there can be more than one version. See the section named "How to determine which versions of the .NET Framework are installed" in the list of framework version numbers I linked to above which gives more information about this.