# Using NUnit with Visual C# Express 2010 and .net 4

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, nunit

I have looked around SO and the web for quite some time now and I am struggling to find any information for how to setup my C# project for unit tests.

I started on the NUnit main site http://www.nunit.org, the download includes a GUI to run your unit tests, sounds mint.  Only when I try and point the GUI to my .exe, I get an error immediately saying that NUnit is not designed to be run with this framework.  That got me thinking that maybe NUnit doesn't work with .net 4.  Apparently it does, plenty of people online seem to state that they are running NUnit unit tests with .net 4 .... of course they don't seem to go on to say how.

Clicking around google I found what appears to be one of the core members of the NUnit development is a dude called Charlie Poole.  I found he had a launchpad here: https://launchpad.net/nunit-xtp.  The version numbers are newer than on the main NUnit site.  When I downloaded the project however, it is just the codebase and solution for the NUnit framework with no GUI.  There is a command line runner included but I really need something visual.

We do have jetbrains teamcity as a BMS so I am now going down the path of maybe trying to integrate NUnit into the build pipeline somehow.  If anyone can shed any light on how they got NUnit working with an express edition of c# that would be wonderfully helpful.

Edit : I have the teamcity BMS running the tests now, so that part is no longer a problem.  However, waiting for the build each time just to find a NullException error or something doesn't really cut it.  I have to get the GUI runner working.  I found this question [NUnit isn't running Visual Studio 2010 code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/930438/nunit-isnt-running-visual-studio-2010-code) but even that isn't fixing it for me.  The error has now updated to read version v4.0.30319, so the config changes have taken effect.  Same old error though :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right I sussed it out.  there is a very similar question here:
[NUnit isn't running Visual Studio 2010 code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/930438/nunit-isnt-running-visual-studio-2010-code)

Only what it doesn't mention is that there are multiple config files for NUnit.  I just assumed it would suffice to edit nunit.exe.config.  This did indeed update the settings as I saw it in the error message.  However, the nunit gui runner must make use of one of the other multiple .config files.  I simply went through them all and added the two required settings.

Make sure that you run the correct .exe.  One is called "nunit.exe" and it seems like the correct one to use.  The other one is called "nunit-x86.exe" and if your app is 32bit then you have to run this one.  If "nunit.exe" was names "nunit64.exe" I think I would have noticed that much sooner.

You must also make sure that you check the version number of the CLR matches the setting you are pasting into those config files.  Use this link to work out your current CLR version number. [How do I find out what CLR i am using?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161119/how-do-i-find-out-what-clr-i-am-using)  I am Microsoft Visual C# 2010 Express and my CLR version number is v4.0.30319

Answer (score 0):

The unit tests should be in a seperate assembly (of type class library). If you point NUnit to that assembly, it will run. Same applies to the command line runner (which is normaly used in automated build processes).

Comment: Yeah i tried that.  I have my tests in a seprate project in the same solution.  If I try and open the .dll with nunit.exe I get the same error.  "You may be attempting to load an assembly built with a later version of the CLR than the version under which NUnit is currently runnin (2.0.50727) or trying to load a 64-bit assembly into a 32 bit process."

Comment: You have to use the .net 4.0 test runner, you currently are using the .net 2.0 one. What version of NUnit are you using? Did you select the 4.0 runtime in File -> Select Runtime?

Comment: Yep!  File->.net 4.0, File->open project ..... same error.  I think the number in the error is maybe a CLR version number.

Comment: yes it is, it is the .net 2.0 runtime version number (which is used until .net 3.5 sp1 as it is the same runtime underneath). I have no idea why this happens.

Comment: nope me neither ... nothing really online about it - this sucks

Answer (score 0):

The default NUnit distro includes a GUI runner called 'nunit.exe'. If using it, I set my debug target on my test assembly to load the GUI runner with the appropriate config.

Comment: hi Ritch thanks for the reply.  could you elaborate a little on that answer.  I'm not sure i know what you mean by "debug target".